# create folder with custom content type using rest api

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem

I am trying to `create a folder in a document library with a custom content type`. The custom content type is based on default `document set content type`.

The code below is straight forward in creating a folder, but I can't seem to find a way to assign the content type to that folder.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
var pCreate = jQuery.ajax({
"url"        : _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Folders/add('SiteCollectionDocuments/newfolder')",
"type"       : "POST",
"headers"    : { 
                "accept"          : "application/json; odata=verbose", 
                "content-type"    : "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
               }
}); 

jQuery.when(pCreate).always(function (data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: You need to pass the `Slug` in headers. Try using solution given [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/creating-a-document-set-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/m-p/39445) and [here](https://julieturner.net/2016/11/create-sharepoint-document-set-and-set-metadata-using-rest/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this SharePoint REST API code to create a folder with document set content type:

```
function createFolder(libraryName, folderName, folderContentTypeId) {
    //site URL
    var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    // path of the SharePoint library
    let libraryUrl = webUrl + "/" + libraryName;

    var folderPayload = {
        'Title': folderName,
        'Path': libraryUrl
    };

    //Create Folder resource
    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + libraryName,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(folderPayload),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Slug": libraryUrl + "/" + folderName + "|" + folderContentTypeId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

**Usage**:

```
createFolder("LibraryName", "FolderName", "0x0120D520007ACA148760DDC646BBA59538FC81DBF9");
```

**References**:

1. [Create SharePoint Document Set (and set metadata) using REST](https://julieturner.net/2016/11/create-sharepoint-document-set-and-set-metadata-using-rest/)
2. [Is it possible to create a Document Set using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114882/is-it-possible-to-create-a-document-set-using-rest-api)
3. [Creating a Document Set with the SharePoint 2013 REST API](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/creating-a-document-set-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/m-p/39445)

Comment: I have seen the code above a lot times, why do I still have to use the _vti_bin? that's old and probably outdated.

Comment: Did you try it? Is it working for you?

Comment: If you don't want to use above API, you can try creating a folder and then update it's content type as given at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251690/how-to-create-folder-with-custom-content-type-in-rest-with-spfx

Comment: I am doing just that, but the problem is that the folder icon does not change. It still looks like a folder, rather than a document set. I tried to use ProgId:"SharePoint...." but did not wokr

Comment: "ProgID": "Sharepoint.DocumentSet"